# Prometheus UI, Grafana settings for spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am using spring boot 2.0 and added the below dependencies in POM

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My application.yml looks like this

`management.endpoints.web.base-path = /manage
 management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = "*"
 endpoints.prometheus.enabled = true`

when I access Prometheus at

> localhost/manage/prometheus

I am able to see all the metrics.

Next, my target is to see the above metrics in Prometheus UI. For this, I added the below dependencies in my POM

```
   <dependency>  
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_spring_boot</artifactId>
        <version>${prometheus.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
        <version>${prometheus.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${prometheus.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

What are the next steps for me to see metrics in Prometheus UI, final target is to integrate Prometheus to Grafana.

PS: I did a search on google and tried adding prometheus.yml and adding annotations like @EnablePrometheusEndpoint nothing worked as all the articles are old.

Edit : Also how to configure prometheus.yml ( metrics_path, targets)if the spring boot jar is hosted in different host (Azure/AWS) and prometheus server is in different host.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring Boot 2 and micrometer you don't need to add the extra dependencies, they are imported when you added `micrometer-registry-prometheus`. if you are able to see the metrics on localhost/manage/prometheus your configuration on the spring-boot side is fine. there is no need to configure anything more.

To see the metrics in Prometheus you need:

1. install Prometheus Server https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/
2. configure Prometheus to scrape (pull) the metrics from your server. for that you will need to modify the prometheus.yml file by adding a new job (don't forget to restart Prometheus after changing the yml file)

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'mySpringBoot'
    metrics_path: '/manage/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['springBootHost:springBootPort']
```

3. once this is configured, go to the Prometheus UI, check that the target is `UP` - http://localhost:9090/targets (assuming Prometheus runs on localhost)
4. if you don't see your target or you see it as `DOWN` there is a configuration or network problem.

the following steps are straight forward, with lot of documentation elsewhere:

5. next step is to install Grafana
6. now configure Prometheus as a data-source in Grafana
7. start plotting your metrics.

Comment: Thanks Yarix for clear explanation. Now i have another problem. My microservice is hosted in Azure. So i configured metrics_path : "https://mywebapp.azure.com/prometheus ", scheme: "https", targets: ['localhost:9090']. When i access http://localhost:9090/targets  my job is down because the final URL i see is https://localhost:9090https://mywebapp.azure.com/prometheus  which is wrong, how to resolve this does microservice and prometheus need to be on same host ?

Comment: the metrics_path is wrong, you should just write '/manage/prometheus' or '/prometheus' depending on how you configured the spring-boot.

where does prometheus server runs? also in Azure? on the same machine of the application?

the targets should be ['yourSpringBootServer:port']

Comment: Prometheus server is running on my local. metrics_path of /manage/prometheus does not work as host is not my local.

Comment: It's not working because your target is wrong. The target should be mywebapp.azure.com.  also, make sure you can access mywebapp.azure.com/manage/prometheus from your local machine.

Comment: It did not work it says mywebapp.azure.com is not valid host name

Comment: Share your application yml and prometheus yml

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot api application configure with prometheus and grafana on windows.

> 1. Create spring boot application and add dependency in pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
 <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> if its running go to your browser and type ‘http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus’ and you will get all metrics.

2. Download and install Prometheus Server  https://prometheus.io/download/
   and extract the zip and run prometheus exe.
3. for that you will need to modify the prometheus.yml file by adding a new job (don't forget to restart Prometheus after changing the yml file)

Note : configure spring application with prometheus.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'SpringBootApplicationName
    metrics_path: ‘actuator-prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [‘IPADDRESS:springBootApplicationPort]
```

4. once this is configured, go to the Prometheus UI, check that the target is `UP` - http://localhost:9090/targets (assuming Prometheus runs on localhost)
5. go to ‘http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus’  and select one metrics and paste in - http://localhost:9090/graph  and click on execute. example you can select one CPU and HTTP metric like  - ‘http_server_request_seconds_max’

the following steps are straight forward, with lot of documentation elsewhere:

6. next step is to install Grafana from - https://grafana.com/grafana/download?platform=windows
     and extract the zip and run the grafana-server.exe and check on your browser ‘http://localhost:3000’
7. now login as a default username ‘’admin and password ‘admin’ and go to setting select the deshboard and create a datasource and select prometheus and type url of prometheus like - ‘’http://ipaddress:pord of prometheus.
8. and go to graph and click edit and select datasource and  type your metric query like ‘http_server_request_seconds_max’
   9.start plotting your metrics.